# General Solution and Particular Solution of Recurrence Equation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I am given:

$S_{n+2} = S_{n+1}+S_{n} + {2}$ for $\forall n \in N$

My question is how do I find the general solution of the recurrence equation. And the particular solution where $S_0=1$ and $S_1 = 5 $?

Comment: If $S_n = T_n - 2,$ then $T_{n+2} = T_{n+1} + T_n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you go from inhomogeneous to homogeneous:
$$
S_{n+2} = S_{n+1} + S_n + 2 \\
S_{n+3} = S_{n+2} + S_{n+1} + 2 \\
$$
so
$$
S_{n+3} - S_{n+2} = S_{n+2} - S_{n}
$$
or 
$$
S_n  = 2 S_{n-1} + 0 \cdot S_{n-2} - S_{n-3}
$$
then you solve that one, using the initial conditions.
The characteristic polynomial is:
$$
p(t) = t^3 - 2 t^2 + 1
$$
We guess the root $r_1 = 1$ and have
$$
p(t) = (t - 1)(t^2 - t - 1)
$$
so the other two roots are
$$
r_{2,3} = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}
$$
where $r_2$ is the golden ratio. This gives
$$
S_n = 
k_1 1^n + 
k_2 \left( \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} \right)^n + 
k_3 \left( \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2} \right)^n 
$$
We have 
$$
S_2 = S_1 + S_0 + 2 = 5 + 1 + 2 = 8
$$
We get the linear system
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} & \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2} \\
1 & \left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2 & \left(\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
k_1 \\
k_2 \\
k_3
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
5 \\
8
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The numerical solution is $k_1 = -2$, $k_2 = 3.95967$, $k_3 = -0.95967$, so
$$
S_n = 
-2 + 
3.95967 \left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n 
-0.95967 \left(\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n
$$
Algebraic solution:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} & \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2} & 5 \\
1 & \left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2 & \left(\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2 & 8
\end{array}
\right)
\to \\
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & -1 & -3 \\
1 & \left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2 & \left(\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2 & 8
\end{array}
\right)
\to \\
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 0 & 0 & -2 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
1 & \left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2 & \left(\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2 & 8
\end{array}
\right)
\to \\
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 0 & 0 & -2 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
0 & \left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2 & \left(\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2 & 10
\end{array}
\right)
\to \\
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 0 & 0 & -2 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 
\left(\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2 
- \left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2 & 
10 - 3 \left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2
\end{array}
\right)
\to \\
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 0 & 0 & -2 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 
\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2} - \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} & 
7 - 3 \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}
\end{array}
\right)
\to \\
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 0 & 0 & -2 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \left( 3 \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} - 7 \right)/\sqrt{5}
\end{array}
\right)
\to \\
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 0 & 0 & -2 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{11}{2\sqrt{5}} + \frac{3}{2} \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{11}{2\sqrt{5}} + \frac{3}{2}
\end{array}
\right)
$$
So this gives
$$
S_n = -2 +
\frac{3+11/\sqrt{5}}{2} \left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n +
\frac{3-11/\sqrt{5}}{2} \left(\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n
$$

Answer (score 0):

Just rewrite it as $S_{n+2} + a = S_{n+1} + a + S_{n} + a$
What is $a$? Apparently $a = 2$ in your example.

Now put: $T_n = S_n + 2$.
You get: $T_{n+2} = T_{n+1} + T_{n}$
This is a linear recurrence relation.
From here you can find the characteristic polynomial, and its roots $x_1$
and $x_2$ (in this case these are the golden ratio and its conjugate).

The general solutions is then:
 $T_{n} = C_1 . x_1^n + C_2 . x_2^n$
Now you just have to find the constants $C_1$ and $C_2$.
For doing this use what you know about $T_0$ and $T_1$,
build a system and solve it for $C_1$ and $C_2$.

Answer (score 0):

The key point is: consider the sequence $$R_n:=S_n+2$$
then $R_{n+2}=R_{n+1}+R_n$ and you have a Fibonacci-type recurence (the standard Fibonacci is for $R_1=R_2=1$). Apply the standard method of solving linear recurrences (just google for "method of solving linear recurrences")